# firewall-cmd does not block port specified

Tags: firewall, firewalld

I added a rich rule to block connections to a DNS server in order to test another process and packet captures show that packets sent by the IP address specified by the following rich-rule are still accepted.

```
block
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

dmz
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

drop
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

external
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

home
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client samba-client ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

internal
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client samba-client ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

public (default, active)
  interfaces: eno16780032
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client samba ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule family="ipv4" source address="10.7.6.11/32" drop
trusted
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

work
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ipp-client ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```